Vectorizing irregular and non SIMD register width multiple loop
Assume the function below. There are two extents that have been picked to be 3 and 17. We wish to vectorize SomeWork (it is in the translation unit and simple).
The naive approach I take is to flatten the iteration space and distribute the work onto the SIMD lanes in loop over  this_lane_index (at least I hope the compiler can see that).
The questions are:
What hint could I give to the compiler to help it vectorize? Should I rewrite the loops ? What invariant can I fix/hint to the compiler ? Are there compiler flags, pragmas, intrinsics etc. that could help ?
I have read https://llvm.org/docs/Vectorizers.html already.
https://godbolt.org/z/h84Gvveqz
#include <cstdint>

template <typename Functor>
void Flattened(Functor some_work) {
    static constexpr uint64_t kExtent0 = 3;
    static constexpr uint64_t kExtent1 = 17;

    static constexpr uint64_t kFlattenedExtent = kExtent0 * kExtent1;

    static constexpr uint64_t kLaneCount = 8;

    uint64_t i_flattened_extent = 0;
    for(;
        (i_flattened_extent + (kLaneCount - 1)) < kFlattenedExtent;
        i_flattened_extent += kLaneCount) {
        for(uint64_t i_lane_index = 0; i_lane_index < kLaneCount; ++i_lane_index) {
            const uint64_t this_flattened_index = i_flattened_extent + i_lane_index;

            const auto dimension_0_index = (this_flattened_index / (1)) % kExtent0;
            const auto dimension_1_index = (this_flattened_index / (1 * kExtent0)) /* % kExtent1 */;

            some_work(i_lane_index, dimension_0_index, dimension_1_index);
        }
    }

    for(uint64_t i_lane_index = 0; i_lane_index < kLaneCount; ++i_lane_index) {
        const uint64_t this_flattened_index = i_flattened_extent + i_lane_index;

        if(this_flattened_index < kFlattenedExtent) {
            const auto dimension_0_index = (this_flattened_index / (1)) % kExtent0;
            const auto dimension_1_index = (this_flattened_index / (1 * kExtent0)) /* % kExtent1 */;

            some_work(i_lane_index, dimension_0_index, dimension_1_index);
        }
    }
}

void instantiate(double* __restrict a_array, double* __restrict b_array, double* __restrict c_array, uint64_t lda, uint64_t ldb, int64_t ldc) {
    Flattened([=](uint64_t, uint64_t dimension_0_index,
                  uint64_t dimension_1_index) {
        // With a,b,c being arrays of double (with restrict).
        c_array[dimension_0_index + ldc * dimension_1_index] =
            42.0 * a_array[dimension_0_index + lda * dimension_1_index] +
            b_array[dimension_0_index + ldb * dimension_1_index];
    });
}


Vectorize for what SIMD ISA?  x86 AVX2 or AVX-512?  AArch64 NEON/ASIMD or SVE?  RISC-V extension V?  What is SomeWork()?  There's pretty much zero chance of vectorizing with a non-inline function-call inside the inner loop.  Does it access arrays at some range of indices, or only at the indices given as function args?  Due to the modulo, unrolling across multiple iterations isn't necessarily contiguous indices, so double-nested loops would probably be better to let the compiler try to vectorize the inner.

With small odd sizes for ranges of contiguous access you might need manual vectorization for good results.  Or at least as a starting point to think about what we want to try to get a compiler to generate across ISAs.

As said, SomeWork is in the same translation unit (typically an always inline c++ template), small (no inner loops and just multiply/add), access only at the index i_lane_index, dimension_0_index, dimension_1_index.

And it doesn't use any static storage to keep state across calls, so it's just an in-place modification of an element?  So if the loop around it was simple, it would trivially auto-vectorize, like vpaddd or something for int32 increments?  Your example would be a lot better with a sample definition that does something += 123; for example.

The reason I'm not specifying an ISA is that I would like to let the compiler do the work. For that, I'm looking at ways that could help it understand the code.
The work in SomeWork is perfectly independent from a lane to another. The extent are compile time known, and the compiler can see through the modulo. The load/store are "contiguous", because while lane 0 could see index (2,1) and lane 1 (0,2), these indices map to a 2d array with no weird stride/leading dimension/subview. This is known a compile time,

Ok, so you require code that can vectorize for every vector ISA GCC supports, or you don't care which it does/doesn't vectorize for.  So if I'm playing around with it on https://godbolt.org/ I should just pick an ISA and assume it's fine on others with whatever cost heuristics GCC or Clang use there?  Most projects have one or two ISAs they care most about.

AVX2 and Neon/SVE are enough. Exotic stuff is not of interest. That said, would it be reasonable to say that if it vectorizes on say, x86, it is likely that it is will vectorize on other ISA provided a ~ 1 to 1 mapping of the operations to the other instruction set ?

Probably, unless the compiler needs AVX-512 masked loads/stores to make it worthwhile vectorizing, then it probably wouldn't vectorize for NEON, only SVE.

There are various things in this code that in my experience compilers currently don't deal with graciously, but you can do them by hand

Why exactly are you "flattening" a loop and then doing an expensive modulo to split up the loop counter again?  Compilers normally have an easier time vectorizing with nested loops.  Also you pass i_lane_index as an arg to the function, but it doesn't use it; what's up with that?  (It doesn't even name that parameter, which I don't think is valid syntax.)

The right operand of the modulo is known at compile time, it is 3 in the sample. The work in SomeWork is small in the example shown above, but in practice, it could be a full-blown high order stencil which would dwarf the modulo cost (which is compile time known anyway). We can replace the modulo with a chain of divisions, but that would increase latency (right?) if not compile time known. Were that modulo a runtime operation, then not having a vectorized mod would probably be a limiting factor.

Ho and in c++, you avoid unused function argument by not giving them name. (same as casting it void). This is std c++ not std c AFAIK.
